# Нужно чтобы кнопка не работала, если нет определенных условий

Tags: python, tkinter

Как сделать так, чтобы кнопка не работала если нет определённых условий, допустим у какой-то переменной низкое число

Comment: В обработчик нажатия кнопки вставляете if, который проверяет, что в переменной не "низкое" число. Если не "низкое", то выполняете действие (кнопка работает всегда, но действие выполняется только при определенных условиях).

Answer (score 1):

вот пимерный код(кнопка не сработает если число меньше 10)

```
def on_click():
    if number<10:
        pass
    else:
        print("кнопка работает")
btn(command=on_click).pack()
```

(изменено по советам insolor, Эникейщик)

Comment: Вот так `btn=Button(command=on_click).pack()` в btn запишется результат выполнения pack, который всегда None

Comment: а еще после этого кнопка перестанет быть кнопкой

Comment: да согласен, сейчас уберу это